# Java convert Json array to typed List<T>

Tags: java, android, json, list

I have a webservice that sends a typed arraylist which I capture via HttpResponse like so:

```
// create GET request
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8084/MinecraftRestServer/webresources/Items");
// execute GET request
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
// check response
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
if (statusCode == 200) { // response OK
    // retreive response
    List<Recipe> recipesList = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
    HttpEntity jsonObj = response.getEntity();
            //What's next?
```

The array that's being sent from the webservice looks like this:

```
recipesList.add(new Item(1, 11, "diamond_ingot", "Diamond ingot",
                "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1", "air,diamond_ore"));
recipesList.add(new Item(2, 11, "iron_ingot", "Iron ingot",
                "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1", "air,iron_ore"));
```

And comes out in this format:

```
[{"recipeCategory":11,"recipeImageID":"diamond_ingot","recipeDescription":"Diamond ingot","recipeLocations":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1","usedImages":"air,diamond_ore","recipeID":1},{"recipeCategory":11,"recipeImageID":"iron_ingot","recipeDescription":"Iron ingot","recipeLocations":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1","usedImages":"air,iron_ore","recipeID":2},{"recipeCategory":11,"recipeImageID":"gold_ingot","recipeDescription":"Gold ingot","recipeLocations":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1","usedImages":"air,gold_ore","recipeID":3},{"recipeCategory":11,"recipeImageID":"diamond_ore","recipeDescription":"Diamond ore","recipeLocations":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1","usedImages":"air,wooden_pickaxe","recipeID":4},{"recipeCategory":11,"recipeImageID":"iron_ore","recipeDescription":"Iron ore","recipeLocations":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1","usedImages":"air,wooden_pickaxe","recipeID":5},{"recipeCategory":11,"recipeImageID":"gold_ore","recipeDescription":"Gold ore","recipeLocations":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1","usedImages":"air,wooden_pickaxe","recipeID":6},{"recipeCategory":2,"recipeImageID":"diamond_boots","recipeDescription":"Boots (Diamond)","recipeLocations":"0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1","usedImages":"air,diamond_ingot","recipeID":7},{"recipeCategory":2,"recipeImageID":"gold_boots","recipeDescription":"Boots (Gold)","recipeLocations":"0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1","usedImages":"air,gold_ingot","recipeID":8},{"recipeCategory":2,"recipeImageID":"iron_boots","recipeDescription":"Boots (Iron)","recipeLocations":"0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1","usedImages":"air,iron_ingot","recipeID":9},{"recipeCategory":2,"recipeImageID":"diamond_leggings","recipeDescription":"Leggings (Diamond)","recipeLocations":"1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1","usedImages":"air,diamond_ingot","recipeID":10},{"recipeCategory":2,"recipeImageID":"gold_leggings","recipeDescription":"Leggings (Gold)","recipeLocations":"1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1","usedImages":"air,gold_ingot","recipeID":11},{"recipeCategory":2,"recipeImageID":"iron_leggings","recipeDescription":"Leggings (Iron)","recipeLocations":"1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1","usedImages":"air,iron_ingot","recipeID":12},{"recipeCategory":2,"recipeImageID":"diamond_chestplate","recipeDescription":"Chestplate (Diamond)","recipeLocations":"1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1","usedImages":"air,diamond_ingot","recipeID":13},{"recipeCategory":2,"recipeImageID":"gold_chestplate","recipeDescription":"Chestplate (Gold)","recipeLocations":"1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1","usedImages":"air,gold_ingot","recipeID":14},{"recipeCategory":2,"recipeImageID":"iron_chestplate","recipeDescription":"Chestplate (Iron)","recipeLocations":"1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1","usedImages":"air,iron_ingot","recipeID":15},{"recipeCategory":2,"recipeImageID":"diamond_helmet","recipeDescription":"Helmet (Diamond)","recipeLocations":"1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0","usedImages":"air,diamond_ingot","recipeID":16},{"recipeCategory":2,"recipeImageID":"gold_helmet","recipeDescription":"Helmet (Gold)","recipeLocations":"1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0","usedImages":"air,gold_ingot","recipeID":17},{"recipeCategory":2,"recipeImageID":"iron_helmet","recipeDescription":"Helmet
```

My question is, how can I convert this back into an arraylist (`ArrayList<Item>`)
There is already an Item class present in the client application.

I've read examples about the Gson library but it seems it's not included anymore when compiling in API 17.

What would be the easiest approach?

Comment: u mean to say u wanna parse the json into arraylist?

Comment: @MT8 yes, it's a typed arraylist with the class Item as type

Comment: create an arraylist instance , parse the JSON , store in arraylist , whats d prob ??

Comment: `I've read examples about the Gson library but it seems it's not included anymore when compiling in API 17.` This is wrong. `GSON` was never included along with the android api. You need to download the jar or add it to `dependencies` block in `build.gradle` if using `Android Studio`

Comment: @RobbieVercammen Have a look at my answer. It shows how you can parse the JSON string to a typed List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and include `GSON` jar from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) in your project if using Eclipse.

If using Android Studio then open your `build.gradle` and add the below to your `dependencies` block. Or again you can choose not to use maven and simply drop the jar in your lib folder.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

Next, use `GSON` to construct a list of items.
Make sure you have your `Item.java` class with same member names as in the `JSON` response

```
 List<Recipe> recipesList = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
 HttpEntity jsonObj = response.getEntity();
 String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
 Log.d("TAG", data);
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
 recipesList = gson.fromJson(data, new TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.getType());
```

Make sure you handle the exceptions appropriately.

Comment: I'm giving your approach a try! I've added the gson lib already but now I'm running into a networkonmain thread exception. Hang on :)

Comment: You shouldn't be doing any network operation on the main thread. If you have trouble fixing the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` there are many answers already for this - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=networkonmainthread

Comment: I've found an answer for that, I surrounded it with a new runable and managed to keep the list waiting before filling it's contents.
But I'm still getting a connection refused when calling my webservice on localhost.

Comment: I think using localhost on your emulator or device will not work. You will probably need to use the IP address of the machine which is hosting the websevice.

Comment: Nope, it were the permissions that were missing! It worked, I've got my data back from the webservice. Thanks a lot. Btw, it does work on localhost if you open up the port for private devices ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to parse the incoming JSON. ([Quick introduction](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes))

If you already have a Class with the appropriate properties, it can be as easy as something like this:

```
public class Items {
    private List<Item> items;
    // getter+setter
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Items = mapper.readValue(src, Items.class);
```

See [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDataBinding) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1 : Item obj=new Item;

Step 2: Parse the json formar for example here :

[[Example1][1]

Step 3: while parsing put ur values in obj :

obj.recipeCategory=value1;

Step 4: insret ur obj into arraylist:

arrayList.add(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should using json-simple library to parse string Json to JsonObject and convert to simple data type.
Example:

```
JSONArray arrJson = (JSONArray) parser.parse("String json");
```

Get each element JSONObject in JSONArray, then parse it to simple data type:

```
long recipeCategory = (long) jsonObject.get("recipeCategory");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Gson` like many users said, here is an example of a RESTfull client using `Gson`:

```
public class RestRequest {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    public <T> T post(String url, Class<T> clazz,
        List<NameValuePair> parameters) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        // Add your data
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        StringBuilder json = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity()
                .getContent());
        T gsonObject = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), clazz);
        return gsonObject;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }

    // Fast Implementation
    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is)
        throws IOException {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    // Read response until the end
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        total.append(line);
    }

    // Return full string
    return total;
    }

}
```

The usage will be something like this:
`new RestRequest("myserver.com/rest/somewebservice", SomeClass.class, Arrays.asList(new BasicValuePair("postParameter", "someParameterValue")));`

Where `SomeClass.class` will be `Recipe[].class` in your case. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315263/error-handling-on-java-sdk-for-rest-api-service/19393551#19393551) question to properly handle server side errors.

Comment: Inputstream to string was my first approach, but Varuns' answer was more accurate. Thanks for the input

Answer (score -1):

Man, google is your friend! A quick search for "android json" or "android json parse" gives you some nice tutorials like [this one](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) or [this here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html).

Comment: more of a comment , les of an answer

Comment: Thanks for the critics... and for the tutorials, they are very helpful. It's not easy to google if you don't know what you have to google for. I guess I was googling too specific.