# Building a RESTful http client for a PCL

Tags: java, c#, android, rest

**Context**

Recently I started working on a mobile project using Xamarin which works with C#/.NET. I came from developing android apps and Java development in general. I always use the same scheme when I build the http client in an app which is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19393551/1403997). I like the concept of overriding only if It's neccesary. I'd like to translate this Java RESTful http client to a C#/.NET RESTful http client.

I'd like to have an API that looks like this:

```
await MakeGetRequest<List<Role>>(Constants.RolesEnpoint)
            .OnSuccess((response) =>
            {
                //Response which is of type List<Role>
                ShowList(response);
            })
            .OnError((exception) =>
            {
                ShowErrorMessage("Unkown error:" + exception.Message);
            })
            .OnInternatServerError(() =>
            {
                ShowErrorMessage("The server explode");
            });
```

And well, mainly the problem that I'm facing is that I'm not really sure about how to implement those lambda callbacks. What I've done so far is:

```
    //<summary>
    // Makes a get request and deserializes the result JSON as T class objects.
    // Check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22732/3-pcl-rest-functions-post-get-multipart
    //</summary>
    //<param name="endpoint">The endpoint name i.e. "/api/v1/feed"</param>
    //<param name="auth">True if we want to seth the AUTH_TOKEN cookie. False otherwise.</param>
    private async RequestTask<T> MakeGetRequest<T>(string endpoint, bool auth = true)
    {
        await new RequestTask<T>((rt) =>
        {
            try
            {
                ValidateAuthToken();
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(baseAddress, endpoint));
                SetHeaders(request);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken))
                {
                    rt.OnAuthTokenError();
                }
                request.Headers["Cookie"] = authToken;
                request.Method = "GET";

                HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

                if (!response.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
                {
                    rt.OnHttpError(response.StatusCode);
                    switch (response.StatusCode)
                    {
                        case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
                            rt.OnForbidden();
                            break;
                        case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                            rt.OnInternalServerError();
                            break;
                        case HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout:
                            rt.OnRequestTimeout();
                            break;
                        case HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout:
                            rt.OnGatewayTimeout();
                            break;
                        case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                            rt.OnNotFound();
                            break;
                        case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                            rt.OnUnauthorized();
                            break;
                    }
                }

                var respStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                respStream.Flush();

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(respStream))
                {
                    //Need to return this response 
                    string strContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    respStream = null;
                    rt.OnSuccess(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(strContent, dateTimeConverter));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                rt.OnError(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't want a concrete answer, or a full-code answer, just being pointed out in the right direction.

Comment: Well, you just need three functions expecting an Action<HttpWebResponse>, store these actions locally and then call them at the appropiate moment, by the way, your name is Agustin?

Comment: Sounds good, could you provide a small snippet? I thought the same solution but for example, in that class where I'll store locally the `Action<HttpWebResponse>` how I create the [BuilderObject](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html). My main issue is how to call/declare that lambda callback functions. And yes, my name is Agustin :P.

Comment: Also, to be fluent your functions must retur nthe same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, what you want is a fluent api, and it must accept some Actions for it, something like this:

```
public class RestClient
{
    Action<HttpWebResponse> onSuccess;
    Action<HttpWebResponse> onError;
    Action<HttpWebResponse> onInternalServerError;

    public RestClient OnSuccess(Action<HttpWebResponse> Handler)
    {
        onSuccess = Handler;
        return this;
    }

    public RestClient OnError(Action<HttpWebResponse> Handler)
    {
        onError = Handler;
        return this;
    }

    public RestClient OnInternalServerError(Action<HttpWebResponse> Handler)
    {
        onInternalServerError= Handler;
        return this;
    }

    private async RequestTask<T> MakeGetRequest<T>(string endpoint, bool auth = true)
    {

       //lots of code, blablabla, just let's go on the handling

       switch(response.StatusCode)
       {
           case HttpStatusCode.OK:

               if(onSuccess != null)
                   onSuccess(response);
               break;

           case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:

               if(onInternalServerError!= null)
                   onInternalServerError(response);
               break;

           default:

              if(onError!= null)
                   onError(response);
               break;
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: Because of your advantage over people not knowing Spanish.

Comment: what advantage? the question and the answer is in english, what he told is just the question in spanish, so he gave me no more indications than the ones at the question...

Comment: @EZI Crypted language spanish? ¬¬... also, if you don't know what he said, why you suppose it gave me any type of advantage? I started writting the answer BEFORE he told me nothing in spanish, if you read the comments in english you can see it. Yes, it's not correct to use another language, as I told to Eser was the hype, but just downvoting a correct answer because you did not understood a comment is just mean.